# Android starting an activity from background service

Tags: android, android-service

```
public void onCreate()
{ 
    super.onCreate();
    Thread tt = new Thread(){
        public void run()
        {
           Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ActivityClass.class);
           dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
        }
    };
    tt.start();
}
```

by using this way i am try to call my activity from service but my application crash 
please help me out

Comment: Please post the `locat` trace.

Answer (score 0):

Ref Below link:

### http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

`startService(i1);`//Start Service.

Use `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()` because in service we use `startActivityResult()`
method because broadcast receiver will give the response of onresultActivity.. so you could use this line

Use `startActivityForResult(intent,requestcode`) instead of `startActivity()`.

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Just do,

```
   public void onCreate() {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Intent in=new Intent().setClass(yourserviceclass.this,ActivityClass.class);
     in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(in);
}
```